# add a html link button in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty young and new to here so please bear with me. I am making a site and I am trying to create html links output in javascript. I am currently trying this method but it is not working? I am trying to change the 'mything' to show this text and add a link.

The code in javascript where I try to add a button is

```
document.getElementById('mything').innerHTML = place.name+' '+' <button id="edit" type = "button" class = "btn btn-link">(edit)</button>';
```

The bit for button is

```
   $('#mything').on('click', function() {
      $('#stuff2').hide(); 

   })
```

I hope I have put this in right? Thankyou

Comment: What exactly does not work? The click event? What should be the behavior? Should it redirect to the link's page? Or should there be a visible link instead of the button?

Comment: And your code adds a button and hides a (I assume) div, but nowhere do you actually create links via javascript. What are you trying, exactly?

Comment: The link is created in javascript and the button id is what triggers the event

Comment: What do you mean by link? In the context of JavaScript/HTML, a link generally refers to an (anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). Are you referring to buttons that trigger actions?

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, this is what happens. I've commented the code up. Is this what you EXPECT to happen?

```js
// Not sure what the place.name was coming from,
//   created a stub object to field that.
place = {
  name: "Foo"
};

// USe this to create the button, then create the
//   event listener ON the button.
// This uses the browser getElementById...
document.getElementById('mything').innerHTML = place.name+' '+' <button id="edit" type = "button" class = "btn btn-link">(edit)</button>';

// ...while the listener uses jquery to select the
//  element. On clicking, I toggle.
   $('#mything').on('click', function() {
      $('#stuff2').toggle(); 

   })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mything">

</div>
<div id="stuff2">
<p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.</p>

<p>Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at illustrating what I think you're getting at:

```js
var place = {
  name: 'Japan'
};
var span = document.getElementById('mything');
span.innerHTML =  place.name + ' <button id="edit" data-place="' + place.name + '">(edit)</button>';
span.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var place = this.getAttribute('data-place');
  alert(place);
});
```

```html
<span id="mything"></span>
```

Comment: That's works but not what I need, I just want to create a link with a button id from javascript to be placed in a span

Comment: Everything you need to do that is in this example. Here, I'm inserting a `button` into a `div`, but it's the same process for inserting a `button` into a `span`.

Comment: Ok but can you show me an example just for one link please without the areas?

Comment: Updated. I'm still not sure if I understand what you're going for.